# Count of 2 dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, compare

I have 2 dataframes of top songs both on spotify and tiktok. In those dataframes I have colums with the names of the top songs of 2022 and I was wondering how to know the amount of songs that are on both columns of the separate dataframes.

I haven't really try much cause I don't know where to start.

Comment: df1.columns.intersection(df2.columns)?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach is to convert song names columns in both dataframes to set, and then union them with each other

```
set(spotify_df.songName).union(set(tiktok_df.songName))
```